# Limit of an Expression Created with Nest

Tags: warning-messages, syntax, recursion

I have implemented Newton's Method, and I am trying to find the exact value of the zero of a polynomial using `Limit`. The dream is that the following code works:

```
g[x_] := 21 - 3 x - 7 x^2 + x^3;
newtonNextGuess[f_, guess_] := guess - f[guess]/f'[guess];
Limit[Nest[newtonNextGuess[g, #] &, 1, n], n -> Infinity]
```

But this returns an error:

```
Nest: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in
    Nest[newtonNextGuess[g,#1]&,1,n].
```

The error persists if I make `n` an integer by replacing it with `1+Ceiling@Abs@n` as talked about in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43932/limit-of-sequence). So the small question is: why is this error happening? But more importantly, is there way I can get Mathematica to tell me the limit of this sequence? The limit is $\sqrt{3}$, and it would be really nice to get Mathematica to display this explicitly (as opposed to numerically) for a presentation.

Comment: How about `Roots[g[x] == 0, x]`?

Comment: @bills, well yeah I can get the roots with that. :) I'm doing this for a presentation on Mathematica though. I'm demonstrating how you could write a (hopefully) familiar algorithm in Mathematica.

Comment: Because you want the output in rootform, you may use `RootApproximant[]`. `RootApproximant@FixedPoint[newtonNextGuess[g, #] &, 1.]`

Comment: @AnjanKumar ah that works! Thank you. You should consider adding your approach as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain the output in root form, `RootApproximant[]` can be used.

```
RootApproximant@FixedPoint[newtonNextGuess[g, #] &, 1.]
(*Sqrt[3]*)
```

Answer (score 4):

For illustrative purposes:

You can get solution in radicals using[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html):

```
g[x_] := 21 - 3 x - 7 x^2 + x^3;
Solve[g[x] == 0, x]
```

You can implement Newton's method with [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html):

```
FixedPoint[# - g[#]/g'[#] &, 0.1]
```

You can illustrate method(with careful choice of starting point), e.g.

```
nm[x0_] := 
 Arrow /@ MapIndexed[{{#1[[1]], 10 #2[[1]]}, {#1[[2]], 10 #2[[1]]}} &,
    Partition[FixedPointList[# - g[#]/g'[#] &, x0], 2, 1]]
Manipulate[
 Plot[g[x], {x, -2, 10}, Epilog -> {Red, nm[p]}, 
  GridLines -> {x /. NSolve[g[x], x], None}], {p, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're going to be able to get the Newton iteration (using rationals or floats) to converge to an exact Sqrt[3]. You can demonstrate that it's headed there:

```
est = NestList[newtonNextGuess[g, #] &, 1, 6]
est - Sqrt[3] // N

{-0.732051, 0.125092, 0.00130337, 1.6763*10^-7, 2.8865*10^-15, 0., 2.2204*10^-16}
```

So you are effectively at "floating point zero" after about 5 iterations. Of course, the easy way is to use the Root function:

```
Roots[g[x] == 0, x]
x == Sqrt[3] || x == -Sqrt[3] || x == 7
```