# Bug in limit evaluation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

When I try to evaluate the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(2\pi e x!)$$
Mathematica yields Indeterminate as an answer, however, the solution is known to be $2\pi$. What could be the cause of this mistake?

I have noticed that Mathematica has problems with trig functions at infinity when calculating limits, possibly with Series expansions at infinity? Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: As mentioned in the tag description of [bugs]: "This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions. "

Comment: `In[3]:= DiscreteLimit[n*Sin[2*Pi*E*n!], n -> Infinity]

Out[3]= 2 \[Pi]` Voting to close. (There are in this case multiple valid reasons to select)

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43932/82985, topic on math.st https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76098/756502

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are **right** if `n` is discrete (`n ∈ Integers`):

```
  DiscreteLimit[n*Sin[2*Pi*E*n!], n -> Infinity]

  (* 2*Pi *)
```

but if `n ∈ Reals` gives:

```
  Limit[n*Sin[2*Pi*E*n!], n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> n ∈ Reals]

  (* Interval[{-Infinity], Infinity]}] *)
```

and I think that this is the **correct** result. See plot.

```
 Plot[n*Sin[2*Pi*E*n!], {n, 1, 15}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we have the product of two sequences, one of them bounded ($\sin(2\pi\,e \,n!)$), and the other ($n$) divergent, so it is divergent.

You should also take into account that the `DiscreteLimit` is doing the limit over the Integers and NOT the Naturals, so $n\geq 0$.

MMA (ver. 11.2) returns a valid result when using `Limit`:

```
Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0, Limit[n*Sin[2*\[Pi]*E*n!], n -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> True]]

(* Indeterminate *)
```

Anyway, this fails with `DiscreteLimit`:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Integers && x >= 0 && a > 0, DiscreteLimit[x*Sin[a x!], x -> +\[Infinity]]]
```

it returns it unevaluated:

$\underset{\,x\to +\infty }{\text{lim}}x \sin (a\, x!)$

Comment: The form of expression in your 2nd code piece is different from the one in the question…

Comment: @xzczd thanks, corrected!

Comment: You are mistaken, even though it is bounded from above, it is not bounded from below, it behaves as 2Pi/n, so is infinitisimal sequence. Product of two sequences, one of them bounded from below, and the other is infinitely big is infinitely big. That is not the case here.